# WPF обработка аргументов event'а во View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пусть у меня во ViewModel имеется событие с аргументом:

```
public class ExampleArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

Я хочу реагировать на это событие во View **с учетом значения свойства аргумента**. Как я могу это сделать ?

Comment: `void Something(object sender, ExampleArgs eventArgs) {  if(eventArgs.Success){ .... } else {....}` ?

Comment: Зачем (и как) вы хотите реагировать на события в View? Выставляйте свойство и привязывайтесь к нему.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я хочу реагировать на результат выполнения команды, отправляемой из View.

Comment: @tym32167 только знакомлюсь с wpf, и везде бьют по рукам за code-behind, потому ищу вариант возможно через биндинги.

Comment: зачем вам вообще событие во вьюмодели? И как именно view должен на него отреагировать?

Comment: @tym32167 допустим, view должен проиграть анимацию, выбор которой зависит от результата выполнения команды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если Вы хотите проиграть анимацию по результату команды - Вам необходимо в Вашей моделе создать свойство которое будет хранить результат Вашей команды:

```
     public bool Success { get; set; }
```

и потом привязать Вашу через DataTrigger к Вашей анимации.

```
        <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Success}" Value="True">
        // Ваша анимация когда успех
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>

                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard> 
              <Storyboard>

              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>  
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Success}" Value="False">
        // Ваша анимация когда не успех
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>

                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard> 
              <Storyboard>

              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>  
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```